# Mysterious angular behaviour - Some forms submit on enter, others don't

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, jquery-events

I am dealing with an inconsistent behaviour with Angular and the way it handles form submissions.

I have a project with various forms. When a user is in "Read only" mode the forms do not have a submit button and I want the form not to be submittable.

Most forms behave correctly except one that does submit on Enter even when no submit button is present.

I have created a plunkr with the two forms below:
One form doesn't submit on enter, the other one does.

Plunkr link: http://embed.plnkr.co/TZEJPVivIUTdtIdGeW9P/

The forms are nearly identical. I haven't found a difference that could be causing this.

Can you help me with ideas how to debug this?
What causes this difference in behaviour?

Comment: _"When there is no submit button, all forms do not submit"_ That may be true in some of your cases for some reason, but it's not correct in general. _"the submit button is not rendered because of an ng-if directive"_ Not in your example.

Comment: No, in my example feel free to delete the button entirely and the form will still submit.
I see a lot of stackoverflows for people asking for solutions on how to make a form submit on enter and the solution is random javascript events, and here you have my simple form that somehow does it by itself

Comment: As I said: That's the expected behavior. To be precise: A possible behavior, because it somewhat depends on the browser. The HTML specification also requires that, if there is a submit button, but it's disabled, the form will not submitted on enter. So if in your example `sendingData` was `true` submission on enter also wouldn't work.

Comment: You say it's "expected behaviour" but I don't believe that. All other forms don't behave like that. So anyway, how do you make it NOT submit on enter?

Comment: Software development is not about beliefs. Feel free to read the [relevant section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission) of the HTML specification. The answer to your question is the answer to the question why do "all other forms" not behave like that. Obviously this form **is** different. Maybe the others have a disabled submit button or catch the keypress event.

Comment: I added a form in my plunkr where the form submits on enter and another one where it doesn't. Can you try to explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this inconsistent behaviour was the presence of an invisible input item in the forms:

```
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
<input style="display: none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">
```

Mystery solved